# jQuery on change event not triggered by jQuery itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange, jquery-events

I placed a listener on all checkboxes on my page with `.on('change')`. When clicking on a checkbox it actually detects the change and fires a function. BUT, when I use a jQuery function to set a checkbox to checked like so: `$('#checkboxOne').prop('checked', true)` the `.on('change')` doesn't detect a change? How come?

Comment: Try..`$('#checkboxOne').prop('checked', true).trigger('change')`

Comment: Awesome, that seemed to work! But, is there a way to not have to trigger the change manually?

Comment: No, see my answer below.

Comment: Though you could hack it and trigger a 'click' event on the checkbox, which would toggle the checkbox's checked state as well as causing the 'change' event to fire. Not the right way to do it though.

Comment: @JabbaDaHoot...No..you have to trigger event explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Kartikeya Khosla is right

The 'change' event is only fired when a user triggers it. Setting properties from within your own code will not trigger events.

Comment: So there is no way to listen for triggers fired by code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire jquery function it self, then you should write your function in `$(document).ready(function(){ });`